# Full page image issues

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to create a background image for my site. It is working and making it a full screen background, However, It shrinks my image up, I am not understanding why. It looks like it takes about an inch off of every side.

Here is the code, directly from CSS tricks

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

here is my full css

```
/*!
       * Start Bootstrap - Full HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
       * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
       * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
       */
      * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}


      /* Header Image Background - Change the URL below to your image path (example: ../images/background.jpg) */

      html {
          background: url('/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
      }



      #thanks {

       position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 75px;
        z-index: 15;
        top: 98%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 36px;
        background-color: #3a1e49;
        color: #edcd05 !important;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
         border-radius: 25px;

      }

      #thanks:hover {

        background-color: #edcd05;
        color: #3a1e49;
      } 


      #thanks a {

        color: #edcd05;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 10%;
      }

      #thanks a:hover {

        color: #3a1e49;
      }
```

Below is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html class="full" lang="en">


            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="description" content="">
                <meta name="author" content="">
                <title>Demo</title>
                <link href="css/full.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>
            <!--
                <div id="thanks">
                    <p><a href="thanks.php">Share a Memory</a></p>
                </div>

                -->
                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Does your parent container have any padding applied?

Comment: You need a fiddle b/c I guarantee there's some other CSS that is making this happen - do you have a "normalize" css before this? Example - https://the-pastry-box-project.net/oli-studholme/2013-june-3

Comment: I added my full CSS. Still not working.

Comment: The CSS you have provided works fine for me. Could you please provide your HTML too?

Comment: @Straw Updated my question with the HTML... It's still cropping my image on every side.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq it works fine for me... I thought there may have been some inline styles messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

you made your image cover this means it will extend over the screen.

make sure that your image is larger than (or equal) your screen resolution.
for EX:
if your screen resolution is 1024 * 728 then the image width should be larger than 1024 and the height 728.

Comment: What if I want it on all different screen sizes to fit perfectly though.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq you should use images with large resolution and small size to load quickly. :)

Comment: My resolution is enormous.

Comment: Please respond. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq can you take a screenshot for your page to see what is shrink??